# Where did I make a mistake while trying to derive the CFL condition using the matrix norm method

Tags: matrices, wave-equation, finite-differences, stability-theory, matrix-norms

Using the central difference derivative approximation, the finite difference approximation of the following wave equation:

$$ c^2 u_{xx} = u_{tt} \tag 1$$

can be written as:

$$ U_{i+1, j}= kU_{i, j+1} + (2 - 2k)U_{i, j} + kU_{i, j-1} - U_{i-1, j} \tag 2$$

where:

$$ k = \Bigg(c{\Delta t \over \Delta x} \Bigg)^2 \tag 3$$

Assuming that the initial and boundary conditions are zero, the iteration expression can be written as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\vec U_{i+1}\\\vec U_{i}\end{bmatrix} = M \begin{bmatrix}\vec U_{i}\\\vec U_{i-1}\end{bmatrix} \tag 4$$

In the above expression, $M$ is the iteration matrix and it is defined as:

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix} A & -I\\I & O\end{bmatrix} \tag 5 $$

where $I$ is the identity matrix, $O$ is the zero matrix and $A$ is the following tridiagonal matrix:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 
2-2k & k & 0\\
k & 2-2k & k\\
0 & k & 2-2k\\
\end{bmatrix} \tag 6$$

Since there are no boundary conditions in the form of derivatives, the stability condition is:

$$ c{\Delta t \over \Delta x} \leq 1 \tag7 $$

This is the Courant–Friedrichs–Lewy (CFL) condition.

I have studied the finite difference method from [this](https://wp.kntu.ac.ir/ghoreishif/smith.pdf) book. The way I understand this method, the method is stable by making sure that the first, second or infinity norm of the matrix $M$ is less or equal to one. I am trying to derive the CFL condition by analyzing the matrix norms, but I am failing. Here is what I did:

By analyzing the first norm I wrote:

$$ k + |2-2k| + k + 1 \leq 1 \tag 8$$

Then I considered the case where $k$ is less or equal to $1$:

$$ k + 2-2k + k + 1 \leq 1 \Rightarrow 3\leq 1 \tag {9}$$

It seems that the CFL condition can not be derived this way, or I made a mistake somewhere.

I tried one more way to derive the CFL condition using the matrix method. The method is described on page $148$ of the book I referenced, and there is also an example for the heat equation on page $150$.

The goal is to make sure that the spectral radius of matrix $M$ is less or equal to one. I have derived the eigenvalues of $M$ to be:

$$\lambda (k,n) = 0.5\bigg(f(k,n) \pm \sqrt {f^2(k,n) - 4}\bigg) \tag {10}$$

where $f(k,n)$ is defined as:

$$ f(k,n) = 2 - 2k \Bigg( 1 + \cos{\Big({n\pi \over N + 1}\Big)} \Bigg) \tag {11}$$
Note that $N$ is equal to three in this case and $n\in\{1, 2, 3\}.$ Plotting the absolute values of the six eigenvalue functions in Matlab, I got the following graph:

[image]

From the graph it can be seen that I made a mistake somewhere again, or I missed something. I tried to figure out what, but failed. The value of the spectral radius should not be equal to one if $k \geq 1$. It should be greater than one. But on my graph it is equal to one.

My question is, where am I making a mistake and how can I derive the CFL condition using the matrix method?